# Using Wildcard Cerificates in Ubuntu server fails to start apache2

Tags: https, apache2, security-certificate, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 with apache 2.4, and I was given a wildcard certificate `*.domain.net` from our IT Head, from a trusted CA and is supposed to be valid. However, a bunch of online forums to help enable in on a subdomain: `corn.domain.net`, failed to make it work.

Here is what I boiled it down to: after enabling the SSL Module, I created a self-signed certificate using this command,

`sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/corn.domain.net.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/corn.domain.net.crt`

after answering the prompts, and editing the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/corn.domain.net-ssl.conf` so `<VirtualHost *:443>`, I  added the lines

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/corn.domain.net.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/corn.domain.net.crt
```

I then enabled the SSL Site using `a2ensite`, verified the syntax was correct using `apache2ctl -t`, and restarted Apache. I navigated to the site **`https://corn.domain.net`** and while it gave a privacy warning (since the certificate was self-signed), the https site worked.

I deleted the Certificate and Key file from the directories from above, and renamed and copied over the wildcard certificate and key so that the names and directories matched the self-signed version. I restarted Apache and it failed to start, but using the self-signed versions worked.

Is there a trick to getting wildcard certificates to work?

Comment: " I restarted Apache and it failed to start".  If so, there are explanations in logfiles/journalctl giving details of what failed. What are they?